# Afterburner.fx fail load resource from object injected

Tags: java, dependency-injection, nullpointerexception, javafx, embedded-resource

I use afterburner.fx DI in my project. All things works fine, except when I try to load a file into a object injected from resources folder.

I try putting `getClass().getResource()`, `Class_name.class.getResource` ... but seems not to be work.

For example, I try to load image to use as icon for app, so I try with (other method that's not works):

```
getIcons().add(new Image(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/img/logo.png")));
```

All ways return same error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Input stream must not be null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the problem that no have relation with Afterburner.fx:

When I create Project with maven, I not include resources from folder img in my POM, so I get always the above error. Perhaps, I can load other default resources like css styles.

After configure correctly my POM, all things work.